# Missing data when decompressing zlib data with Ruby

Tags: ruby, compression, zlib

Well I have a deflated json encoded in a request log and I need to decompress it.

I tried to use zlib, i.e:

> Zlib::Inflate.new(-Zlib::MAX_WBITS).inflate(File.read("PATH_OF_FILE"))

It shows only a part of the JSON. Something like:

> "{\"seq\":53,\"app_id\":\"567067343352427\",\"app_ver\":\"10.3.2\",\"build_num\":\"46395473\",\"device_id\":\"c12f541a-5936-4477-b6fc-653db675d16"

There is a lot of missing data because the deflated data is too big.

**Deflate full data:**

[Check it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJPWL.png).

After testing, I figured out that only **this part is being decompressed:**

[Check it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlXFO.png).

Well I'm a bit confused with this. Could someone could please help me with it?

Comment: Try `File.binread`.